How to set channelId programmatically for OCI Queue service?
This is blog for Oracle Cloud Infrastructure Queue service channels: https://blogs.oracle.com/cloud-infrastructure/post/channels-in-oci-queue
Where we can see section "Sending messages to a specific channel".
I am interested if we can do it programmatically in java (for example).
Here is my QueueProducer:
package com.oehs.service;

import com.oracle.bmc.ConfigFileReader; 
import com.oracle.bmc.auth.ConfigFileAuthenticationDetailsProvider; 
import com.oracle.bmc.queue.QueueClient; 
import com.oracle.bmc.queue.model.PutMessagesDetails; 
import com.oracle.bmc.queue.model.PutMessagesDetailsEntry; 
import com.oracle.bmc.queue.requests.PutMessagesRequest; 
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value; 
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.ConditionalOnExpression;

import java.util.Collections;

@ConditionalOnExpression("${oracle-vault.enabled:false}") public class QueueProducer {

    @Value("${oracle-vault.profile:QUEUE}")
    private String oracleProfile;

    public void produce(String message) throws Exception {
        // Authentication using OCI Config file (~/.oci/config)
        final ConfigFileReader.ConfigFile configFile = ConfigFileReader.parseDefault(oracleProfile);
        ConfigFileAuthenticationDetailsProvider provider =
                new ConfigFileAuthenticationDetailsProvider(oracleProfile);

        // Create Queue Client
        QueueClient queueClient = new QueueClient(provider);
        queueClient.setEndpoint("testEndpoint");

        // Replace with your Queue OCID
        String queueId = "testQueue";

        // Create message details
        PutMessagesDetailsEntry messageEntry = PutMessagesDetailsEntry.builder()
                .content(message) // Message content
                .build();

        // Put the message into the queue
        PutMessagesDetails putMessagesDetails = PutMessagesDetails.builder()
                .messages(Collections.singletonList(messageEntry))
                .build();

        // Create request to put messages
        PutMessagesRequest putMessagesRequest = PutMessagesRequest.builder()
                .queueId(queueId)
                .putMessagesDetails(putMessagesDetails)
                .build();

        // Send the message
        queueClient.putMessages(putMessagesRequest);

        queueClient.close();
    } 
}

Those object for publishing message doesn't contain channelID... Any idea how to do it?
Update: I found that what I need in oracle documentation(https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/api/#/en/queue/20210201/PutMessage/PutMessages), so here is the code:
PutMessagesDetails putMessagesDetails = PutMessagesDetails.builder()
    .messages(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(PutMessagesDetailsEntry.builder()
            .content("EXAMPLE-content-Value")
            .metadata(MessageMetadata.builder()
                .channelId("ocid1.test.oc1..<unique_ID>EXAMPLE-channelId-Value")
                .customProperties(new HashMap<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>() {
                        {
                            put("EXAMPLE_KEY_nwH3Y","EXAMPLE_VALUE_KBPc0dN7O2rp1eVCL3aO");
                        }
                    }).build()).build()))).build();

But, I don't have metadata in my PutMessagesDetails object. I have latest OCI sdk version in my pom.xml file:
<oci-sdk.version>3.18.0</oci-sdk.version>

I am really not sure what am I doing wrong...
